# TF2 Last Map not rotating to First Map

Tags: team-fortress-2, server-administration

My TF2 Trade Plaza server has only 2 maps:

- trade_plaza_2
- trade_plaza_station_square_v1

I have enabled TF2 voting to the the map and it works fine when I am on the first map (trade_plaza_2). When I then get to the next (which is also the last) map (trade_plaza_station_square_v1) and I want to vote to go back to the first map (trade_plaza_2) there are **no maps** to vote for.

So basically I want trade_plaza_2 (the fist map) to be available in the vote list when I am on the trade_plaza_station_square_v1 map (the  second and last map)

I really hope someone out there can help as I have searched and searched and I cannot find anything that refers to this problem.

My `server.cfg` is as follows:

```
// dodbits SRCDS Team Fortress 2 cfg file generator Ver 1.

say "Loading SRCDS Team Fortress 2 cfg file"

// General server name, passwords and contact details 
hostname "Private" 
rcon_password "SomeRandomPassword" 
sv_password "AnotherPassword" 
sv_contact "anEmailAddress" 
sv_tags "" 
sv_region "7" 
sv_lan "0"

// Server bans and server logs 
sv_rcon_banpenalty "15" 
sv_rcon_minfailures "5" 
sv_rcon_maxfailures "10" 
sv_rcon_minfailuretime "30" 
sv_rcon_maxpacketsize "1024" 
sv_rcon_maxpacketbans "1" 
log "on" 
sv_logbans "1" 
sv_logecho "1" 
sv_logfile "1" 
sv_log_onefile "0"   

// Server downloads and files 
// No fast download maximum file size. 16 is def. 64 (max) recommended if you do not have a fast download server. net_maxfilesize "64" 
//Fast download url. Leave blank if you dont have one but set the above to max. 

sv_downloadurl "" 
sv_allowdownload "1" 
sv_allowupload "1" 
sv_consistency "1" 
sv_pure "1" 
sv_pure_kick_clients "0" 
sv_pure_trace "0"

sv_vote_issue_kick_allowed "1" 
sv_vote_kick_ban_duration "10"

sm_advertisements_enabled 1 
sm_advertisements_file "advertisements.txt" 
sm_advertisements_interval 120    

tf_weapon_criticals "0" 
tf_weapon_criticals_melee "0"


// Bandwidth Rates 
sv_maxrate "50000" 
sv_minrate "7500" 
sv_maxupdaterate "66" 
sv_minupdaterate "20" 
sv_maxcmdrate "66" 
sv_mincmdrate "30"

// General server settings 
mp_friendlyfire "0" 
sv_alltalk "1" 
mp_chattime "10" 
sv_use_steam_voice "1" 
sv_allow_voice_from_file "0" 
sv_voiceenable "1" 
mp_allowspectators "1" 
decalfrequency "30" 
mp_flashlight "1" 
mp_footsteps "1" 
mp_autoteambalance "0" 
mp_teams_unbalance_limit "0" 

// Time after the teams become unbalanced to attempt to switch players.
mp_autoteambalance_delay 60

// Time after the teams become unbalanced to print a balance warning
mp_autoteambalance_warning_delay 30

sv_restrict_aspect_ratio_fov "0" 
mp_forcecamera "1" 
sv_cheats "0" 
sv_pausable "0" 
sv_allow_wait_command "0" 
sv_hudhint_sound "0" 
mp_forceautoteam "0" 
mp_falldamage "1" 
mp_fadetoblack "0"

// Movement speed and feel 
sv_gravity "800"

//Round specific cvars  
mp_enableroundwaittime "0" 
mp_bonusroundtime "15" 
mp_restartround "0"

// default is 
mp_stalemate_enable "0" 
mp_stalemate_enable "1"

mp_stalemate_timelimit "240" 
mp_maxrounds "0" 
mp_winlimit "0" 
mp_timelimit "0" 
tf_flag_caps_per_round "3"

// TF2 specific Gameplay and server settings //(ONLY found in TF2)                 
tf_weapon_criticals "0" 
sv_allow_votes "1" 
tf_damage_disablespread "0" 
tf_use_fixed_weaponspreads "0" 
mp_idlemaxtime "5" 
mp_idledealmethod "3" 
mp_respawnwavetime "0" 
mp_disable_respawn_times "1"

// Change to next map immediately upon successful vote     
sv_vote_issue_changelevel_allowed "1" 
sv_vote_issue_kick_allowed "1"

// Change to next map at the end of the round     
sv_vote_issue_nextlevel_allowed "0"

mapcyclefile "mapcycle.txt"

// Execute ban files 
exec banned_user.cfg 
exec banned_ip.cfg 
writeid writeip

------------------------------ END of server.cfg
```

My mapcycle.txt file looks like this:

```
// Default mapcycle file for Team Fortress. 
// 
// DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE! 
// Instead, copy it to mapcycle.txt and modify that file.  If no custom     
mapcycle.txt file is found, 
// this file will be used as the default. 
// 
// Also, note that the "mapcyclefile" convar can be used to specify a     
particular mapcycle file.

trade_plaza_2 
trade_plaza_station_square_v1

------------------------------ END of mapcycle.cfg
```

My maplists.cfg contanis this:

```
"MapLists"
{
    /**
     * Default requests go right to the mapcyclefile.
     */
    "default"
    {
        "target"        "mapcyclefile"
    }

    /* Admin menu, map menu */
    "sm_map menu"
    {
        "file"          "addons/sourcemod/configs/adminmenu_maplist.ini"
    }

    /* Admin menu, map voting menu */
    "sm_votemap menu"
    {
         "target"   "mapcyclefile"
    }

    /* For the "randomcycle" plugin */
    "randomcycle"
    {
        "target"        "default"
    }

    /* For the "mapchooser" plugin */
    "mapchooser"
    {
        "target"        "default"
    }

    /* For the "nominations" plugin */
    "nominations"
    {
        "target"        "default"
    }
}

------------------------------ END of maplists.cfg
```

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer when running a TF2 server, map names are code.

Answer (score 5):

This is from the official Tf2 Wiki:

> If you decide to use a custom map voting plugin, make sure you put the map name in **both** the maplist.txt and the voting list for it to work correctly.
>
> SRCDS (Source Dedicated Server) allows for easily editing of this list of playable maps. which is found in `orangebox/tf/maplist.txt`
>
> To add custom maps, drop the `.bsp` file into the `orangebox/tf/maps` directory and then find the `maplist.txt` at `orangebox/tf/maplist.txt` in your server directories and then add its name on a new line to the list (when listing map names, use the exact name of the .bsp file, without including the .bsp extension).

Did you put the custom maps in your dedicated server files or in your tf2 files? They need to be added to your dedicated server files.

Comment: Thank you for the response Meow Meow.

It is not however, my intent to use a custom map voting plugin. Perhaps in desperation I have mis-configured trying to get this problem resolved, i.e. I am not sure if I have to actually even include anything relating to the SourceMod's maplists.cfg

You can see from my server.cfg I am pointing to the standard mapcycle.txt

Comment: Oh, and yes, my maps are in the **C:\hlserver\tf2\tf\maps** folder

Comment: The orangebox directory hasn't existed in TF2 servers since 2013.

Comment: I think this is the new one. -> "Steam\SteamApps\common\Team Fortress 2\tf\maps"

Comment: ...\Steam\steamapps\common\Team Fortress 2\tf\maps is for the players, not for the server.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. Please note though that the voting works fine from Map1 to Map2. It just doesn't work from Map2 back to Map1 because the voting map list is then empty.. To vote you need to press escape and click on the voting (tick) icon. Hope that helps to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're using SourceMod for voting.

SourceMod's mapchooser has several settings stored in cfg/sourcemod/mapchooser.cfg

In particular, you need to change the setting of `sm_mapvote_exclude` to 0.

Comment: To vote you need to press escape and click on the voting (tick) icon. Hope that helps to clarify. It works fine from Map1 to Map2, but once you are on Map2 and want to vote to go back to Map1, the Map list is empty.